# OpenGLでエラー

Tags: android, android-studio, opengl-es

GoogleサンプルのMediaEffectを使って、OpenGLを動かしてみようと思いAndroid StudioでRUNしたところ以下のようなエラーがでてRUNしなくなりました。
たしか最初にRUNしたときは動いていたのですが。。
どうしたらいいか教えてください。

```
06-14 10:57:47.178    7085-7085/? I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
06-14 10:57:47.257    7085-7085/com.example.android.mediaeffects I/MainActivity﹕ Ready
06-14 10:57:47.281    7085-7101/com.example.android.mediaeffects D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
06-14 10:57:47.284    7085-7085/com.example.android.mediaeffects D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb42b3ef0, tid 7085
06-14 10:57:47.307    7085-7085/com.example.android.mediaeffects D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
06-14 10:57:47.351    7085-7101/com.example.android.mediaeffects D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb43d6240, tid 7101
06-14 10:57:47.365    7085-7101/com.example.android.mediaeffects I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-14 10:57:47.417    7085-7101/com.example.android.mediaeffects D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
06-14 10:57:47.445    7085-7101/com.example.android.mediaeffects W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-14 10:57:47.445    7085-7101/com.example.android.mediaeffects W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb431e160, error=EGL_SUCCESS
06-14 10:57:47.528    7085-7100/com.example.android.mediaeffects D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb42b3cf0, tid 7100
06-14 10:57:47.542    7085-7100/com.example.android.mediaeffects E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 172
    Process: com.example.android.mediaeffects, PID: 7085
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No config chosen
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:869)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1023)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1400)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239)
```

Answer (score 1):

自己レスとなります。
実機を接続したらこのエラーは発生しませんでした。
よって、AVD Managerからエミュータを起動したときの話となります。
とりあえずは実機でやってみます。